# Capture clicks on menu bar for my macOS app

Tags: swift, macos

Below statement captures all clicks inside my app window but does not capture the clicks on the menu bar for my app. I am also unable to capture menu bar click for my app using `addGlobalMonitorForEvents`

```
NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .leftMouseDown , handler: {
            (mouseEvent:NSEvent?) in ....
```

Comment: Use an observer if the menu bar you want to monitor belongs to your application.

Comment: @El Tomato: What kind of observer?

Answer (score 2):

For me, using the `globalMonitor` along with `NSEvent`'s `locationInWindow` property seemed to output coordinates of the click, even when not on the window of the app. Here's my implementation:

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .leftMouseDown) { event in
    print(event.locationInWindow)
}
```

- As a side note, the click coordinates go from (0,0) in the bottom left of my screen to (width,height) of my screen at the top right

Comment: Global event is not called when the window in focus is my app's window and i click on the menu bar.